# Parse.com - Update email for PFUser while using Fb authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, permissions, parse-platform

I'm receiving PFUser properly while log in or sign up through Facebook. My permission array:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me",@"email"];
```

In Parse Data browser, I can see that a user got created with some long string username and proper authData etc. But email field is still empty.

Do I need to make separate call to fill email field for the newly created PFUser ? If Yes then what are the proper steps.

Another question, how forgot password mechanism work for facebook authenticated user in Parse.com ? Do I need to fill email value first by calling graph api and then use that email address for forgot password feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a separate call to fill the email attribute. Once the user is authenticated, you can call the `startForMeWithCompletionHandler:` method of *[FBRequestConnection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequestConnection/#startForMeWithCompletionHandler%3a)* class to get the user info and then save it to the current user. Your calls should look like this:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me",@"email"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && user) {
        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"]
                                         forKey:@"email"];
                [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

About the forgot password for Facebook users, it doesn't make sense since if the user forgot the password, it should change it on Facebook. But, if you call `requestPasswordResetForEmail:` method, it would send instructions for changing the password to the user since the email exists. Take into account that the `logInWithUsername:password:` uses the attribute *username* to log in the user, not the email, and that value it is probably unknown for Facebook users in your app.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yeah it really makes sense. Infact, on requestPassword api call we can say that user is not registered with this email address because user has logged-in with the facebook not with the regular signup authentication process.